# Remove a range on table with JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to remove a range on my table. Here is my HTML code:

```
<td  ><button id="btnRemoveRange" class="pull-left btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-click="removeRange(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
```

And my JS function is this:

```
$scope.removeRange = function(obj){
    obj.parentNode.parentNode.style.display='none';

}
```

But it is not working.

I tried using Span and  it worked with this code:

```
<td><span onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';">x</span></td>
```

Can you please tell me what did I do wrong in the first code?

Thanks

Comment: instead of this use event and inspect elements to reach to parent If using angular why not use ng-class or ng-style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `angular.element().css()` like the following:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.removeRange = function(obj){
    var el = angular.element(document.querySelector( '#btnRemoveRange')).parent();
    //console.log(el);
    el.css('display','none');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div><td><button id="btnRemoveRange" class="pull-left btn btn-xs btn-success" ng-click="removeRange(this)"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Click</button></td></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug it with alert();, I'm not sure whether the function has been executed.
Also it is a best practice to determine whether the element exists - in order to prevent JS errors.

```
$scope.removeRange = function(obj){
    alert("Something is happening?");
    if (obj.parentNode.parentNode)
        obj.parentNode.parentNode.style.display='none';
    return false;
}
```

Another option is to use a raw javascript and define "function removeRange(obj)":

```
<button id="btnRemoveRange" ... onclick="return removeRange(this)">
```